# how to mock jwt.decode inside aws lambda for unitesting

Tags: python, jwt

I have created a lambda that will receive JWT in lambda's event header and subsequently decode the jwt payload and give me the subject.
lambda snippet looks like this:

```
def handler(event, context):
    print("hello world!")
    # print(event)

    message = dict()

    jwt_token = event['headers']['x-jwt-token']
    # more info on PyJWT
    # https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
    try:
        decoded_jwt = jwt.decode(jwt_token,
                                 options={"verify_signature": False})
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        print("Signature expired. Get new one!!!")
        message['Body'] = {
            'Status': 'Lambda failure',
            'Reason': 'JWT Signature expired. Get new one!!!'
        }
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
        print("Invalid Token")
        message['Body'] = {
            'Status': 'Lambda failure',
            'Reason': 'JWT Invalid Token'
        }
    else:
        # all are good to go
        if event['httpMethod'] == 'GET':
            resource_owner_name = "".join(decoded_jwt["subject"])
```

now I have created the below fixtures for my unit tests:

```
sample_events.json
{
  "resource": "/path",
  "path": "/path'",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "x-jwt-token": "welcome.here.1234"
  }
}
```

and in my `test_main.py`

```
def load_json_from_file(json_path):
    with open(json_path) as f:
        return json.load(f)

    @pytest.fixture
    def events():
        return load_json_from_file('unit_tests/fixtures/sample_events.json')
    
    def test_main(events, context):
        # jwt = Mock()
        # jwt.decode.return_value =
        response = handler(events, context)
```

Now I wonder how to bind the jwt and mock it in my `python handler`? what is the solution, is there any other approach which I could follow?

I also tried to patch the Jwt.decode still no luck...anyone can shed some light on patching the jwt decode that might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) to patch a given target:

```
def test_main(events, context):
        with patch("handler.jwt.decode") as decode_mock:
            decode_mock.return_value =
            response = handler(events, context)
```

Just make sure you path the correct path to the patch target.

Comment: It's working...I don't know what I did it was not working now it is. Thanks.